# OpenCV : Circle detection using cvHoughCircle

Tags: c++, opencv, geometry

What does cvHoughCircle return if no circle is detected. I want to use it in a if condition.. And if no circle is detected.. hard code it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ function `cv::HoughCircles` has a void return.

In the example from [the OpenCV documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#void%20HoughCircles%28InputArray%20image,%20OutputArray%20circles,%20int%20method,%20double%20dp,%20double%20minDist,%20double%20param1,%20double%20param2,%20int%20minRadius,%20int%20maxRadius%29), they use the value of `circles.size()` to know how many circles were found. (`circles` is the second argument to `HoughCircles`, where the output is stored.)

However, if you really want to use the C `cvHoughCircles`, it returns a pointer to a `CvSeq` ([documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/dynamic_structures.html#cvseq)). You can check it's `->total` member to see how many circles were returned.